# Performance Comparison - Continue After Last Breakpoint vs Normal Run

Tags: python, debugging, pdb

In terms of performance (memory, running time, etc), what is the difference between a normal run of a Python script vs choosing "continue" after the last breakpoint? Of course, there would be some difference before the last breakpoint, but I am interested in cases when the code before the last breakpoint is not intensive (does not require too much memory/running time).

Usually, if I find my code good after checking the last breakpoint, if the code afterward is not intensive, I just continue. Otherwise (such as using Keras for machine learning), I rerun from the start not using the debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is "it depends". Generally, if you have a debugger enabled execution time is slower, however, if the code you are running is largely C (I'd assume Keras is) then the impact of your debugger will be reduced.

If your process is time-critical or is a long-running task running without the debugger enabled will be faster. Using `python -O` can improve things further stripping out asserts etc